# Insert value of one column from one table to another table based on where condition

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, sql-insert

I have one question . Suppose there is one table rules in which column department, action ,left_source and right_source,left_source_id,right_source_id  is there .Another table is source table where column is name,I'd .
Now i have to insert rules to rule table but in left_source_id and right_source_id i have to insert value from source table based on I'd column . I need some immediate help .
(Source table column I'd contains all the name of left_source and right_source )

Comment: ' i have to insert value from source table based on I'd column' - for example?

Comment: if you can write a select, you can write a insert. Period

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

Insert Select...union all..select for example

```
drop table if exists t,t1;

create table t(id int,leftsource varchar(1),rightsource varchar(1));
create table t1(id int,val varchar(1));

insert into t1 values
(1,'l'),(2,'r');

insert into t
select id,val,null from t1 where id = 1
union all
select id,null,val from t1 where id = 2

select * from t;

+------+------------+-------------+
| id   | leftsource | rightsource |
+------+------------+-------------+
|    1 | l          | NULL        |
|    2 | NULL       | r           |
+------+------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: I don't want a separate table, the table which is "rules" in that only two column value i have to pick from another table based on the condition specified above , all other column values will be hardcoded.

Comment: Imagine t is rules table and t1 is source table